# Configure Accelerometer Bandwidth in the Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, accelerometer, bandwidth

We are working on a project where we need to have good accelerometer data with the Galaxy Nexus. However, we have already tried sampling accelerometer data at 100hz through native c, but the data we are getting is still poor. The Galaxy Nexus has a Bosch BMA220 and it's stated there that the accelerometer bandwidth can be configured. We figure if we could adjust the bandwidth, we could theoretically get better data. So does anyone know how we can have access to the device itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing by bandwidth we are talking about the bandwidth of the lowpass filter. It seems it is perfectly configurable from it's buses, I2C or SPI. I have not been able to tell what bus it is connected to the SoC with but i am going to guess it's one of the I2C buses.

I can't help you with the accessing I2C in userland but this: [Why build android source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101840/why-build-android-source) and other sources here on "android i2c" can probably shed some light on that topic.